# Kernel Code in System Logs

Tags: log

See that in system logs:

```
Jul 23 16:31:17 superlinux1 kernel: [ 1419.790327] show_signal_msg: 24 callbacks suppressed
Jul 23 16:31:17 superlinux1 kernel: [ 1419.790329] psi-plus[5414]: segfault at 10 ip 0000559788fa3308 sp 00007ffebeba3970 error 4 in psi-plus[559788d51000+664000]
Jul 23 16:31:17 superlinux1 kernel: [ 1419.790335] Code: 00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 55 48 89 fd e8 93 ff ff ff 48 89 ef be 18 00 00 00 5d e9 c5 91 db ff 90 0f 1f 40 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 83 ec 18 <48> 8b 7f 10 48 89 74 24 08 48 8d 74 24 08 e8 45 05 00 00 48 83 c4
```

What is this code:

```
00 00 f3 0f 1e fa 55 48 89 fd e8 93 ff ff ff 48 89 ef be 18 00 00 00 5d e9 c5 91 db ff 90 0f 1f 40 00 f3 0f 1e fa 48 83 ec 18 <48> 8b 7f 10 48 89 74 24 08 48 8d 74 24 08 e8 45 05 00 00 48 83 c4
```

How to find out exactly what is it?
If it is a direct processor command, help me to find out what it will do, etc.

Comment: Yes. Very good question. I've seen that code once in a while. I'm also interested in an answer.